# Using a Java Array for Casting

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I am working on a program that will deal with a lot of casting from long primitives.  Is it possible to to use an array for casting instead of using multiple if statements checking for each case?  For example the 0 element to cast to byte, 1 element to short, etc.

I'm working on a cast object that have all the properties, values, and methods needed, but I'm wondering if I'm reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I am writing a program to demonstrate how casting is done.  I was hoping to use some kind of array to cast from long to simulate other primitives, but I think I see how that will not work.  Especially with signed primitives.  It was just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

No. That's not possible. The casting information is specified at the compiled time while the object present in the array are accessed at the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a little vague and difficult to see exactly what you are wanting.

Could you be looking for a `BigInteger` [created](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte[]%29) from a `byte[]`? Then it doesn't matter how many longs you have, just cast them to `byte[]` and rap them in a `BigInteger`.